# how to translate added values in sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im building an app that has sqlite table that I can add values in it , is there a way to display the existed data (already added values into sqlite table) in default device language ?

Comment: Please don't just repost a question that's been put on hold. Instead, [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59003793/edit), following the advice in the banner there, and it will enter a queue where users can vote to reopen it if it's been improved sufficiently.

Answer (score -1):

"Select * from "table"" in your sql query(dao) and print all the entries on the UI / console. You can also check device manager to see the file system on your device and search for db file. However, if your db is encrypted you will need a passphrase to open it. When it comes to seeing data in your default language I don't think there's any reliable way you can get data directly translated in your default language without going through tedious localization process.

Comment: This is not anywhere close to what they're asking. They want existing data automagically translated to another language whenever the user changes the device language.